# UWP COMException on WebView after updating Windows 10 to ver 1803

Tags: webview, uwp, comexception

After updating Windows 10 to version 1803 build 17134 the method GoBack() of the WebView raise the following COM exception:

> $exception    {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005):
>   Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.GoBack()    at
>   LFgroupNative.Form.WebViewV3.act_back(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs
>   e)}   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

[image]

Comment: Can you try the following: Close your VS and then delete the .suo file in your solution and then rebuild it?

Comment: @TheTanic. Doesn't work

Comment: Where does LFgroupNative.Form.WebViewV3 come from?

Comment: Is a Control that inherited from WebView

Comment: Is it open source, because according to the exception message, the problem is inside this control

Comment: No, is a simple component developed by me, it has only two method to handle the start and stop of a wait modal form that can be called only directly in the code.

Comment: Where did you call this method? Could you try to provide a sample to help me see this issue?